# How to subtract one hour from the current date in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script in AutoHotkey (using version 1.1.28) that prints the current date and time in this format: "16-12-2018 08:07"

But I need to subtract one hour from the current date, which is not so easy, especially when at midnight in the first day of the month. How can I do that?

My current script looks like this:

```
!^t::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%{Space}
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add or subtract time from a date-time value:

```
!^t::
CurrentDateTime := "" ; empty this variable (erase its content)
EnvAdd, CurrentDateTime, -1, hour
; equivalent to:
; CurrentDateTime += -1, HH
FormatTime, one_hour_ago, %CurrentDateTime%, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm
; MsgBox, %one_hour_ago%
SendInput %one_hour_ago%{Space}
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/EnvAdd.htm

Comment: Thanks, it works but.. just for the first time. The second time, it will subtract one more hour :) then another one and so on. So 16-12-2018 16:17  -  16-12-2018 15:17  -  16-12-2018 14:17 etc. Tried both of them, they act the same. Is there any way to fix these scripts? Thank you

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it before. You have to empty the variable's content first, otherwise the old value remains in the script's memory. Try the edited answer.